# Locally demoing an asp.net mvc app on a pc without visual studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, publish, web-hosting

I would like to package an asp.net mvc up for a 1 day demo if possible. The demo can be done on a local machine or I am willing to pay for simple hosting if it is a fast deployment.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Well there's probably around a thousand hosting providers you can use. Cloud providers in particular are designed to be allow transient hosting. Or you could just deploy to IIS running on a local machine. It's up to you. Do some research and find what best fits *your* situation. You definitely don't need VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to demo it locally, **you can just use IIS or IIS Express** which should let you run in any Windows and any SKU. you can easily install that using Web Platform Installer.

But I would really consider using Microsoft Azure, which will give you 10 free web sites, no commitment, no tricks.

In fact you can even try it without creating an account or anything, go to:
https://tryappservice.azure.com/

or you can get $200 for a month and 10 perpetually free web sites just by going to: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

best thing is that there is tight integration with Visual Studio, and gives you a great way to learn the cloud.